Unity UI toolkit button callbacks don't work if I disable the UI document and then enable it again
I have a camera setup and I want to display a UI on it. I got a basic UI using UI toolkit shown below:

So I have a keyboard button setup so that when the button is pressed a boolean toggles and turns the UI on (and shows the mouse) or turns the UI off (and hides the mouse). The way I achieved turning the UI on and off is the following:
public bool Locked;                     //the boolean value that controls if the spawnmenu is enabled
private GameObject Camera_Controller;   //the gameobject with the camera controller script on it
private UIDocument SpawnMenu;           //the UI document attached to this gameobject

// Start is called once before the first execution of Update after the MonoBehaviour is created
void Start()
{
    //set the gameobject to the LookTarget gameobject in the scene heirarchy 
    Camera_Controller = GameObject.Find("LookTarget");
    //set the locked variable equal to the RotationLock variable in the Camera_Controller script
    Locked = Camera_Controller.GetComponent<Camera_Controller>().RotationLock;

    //set the spawn menu equal to the UI document attached to this gameobject
    SpawnMenu = GetComponent<UIDocument>();
    //enable or disable the spawnmenu
    SpawnMenu.enabled = Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //determine the state of the locked variable and then enable or disable the spawn menu 
    Locked = Camera_Controller.GetComponent<Camera_Controller>().RotationLock;
    SpawnMenu.enabled = Locked;
}

So the UI can turn on and off by finding the UI document attached to the same gameobject as my script and enabling or disabling it using a bool.
Now my problem is the following:
I have a second script setup to register a callback (which I am not familiar with) with the button elements in the UI document shown below:
private UIDocument Document;
private Button ButtonStraight, ButtonCorner, ButtonFloor;

private void Awake()
{
    Document = GetComponent<UIDocument>();
    ButtonStraight = Document.rootVisualElement.Q("ButtonStraight") as Button;
    ButtonStraight.RegisterCallback<ClickEvent>(OnButtonStraight);

    ButtonCorner = Document.rootVisualElement.Q("ButtonCorner") as Button;
    ButtonCorner.RegisterCallback<ClickEvent>(OnButtonCorner);

    ButtonFloor = Document.rootVisualElement.Q("ButtonFloor") as Button;
    ButtonFloor.RegisterCallback<ClickEvent>(OnButtonFloor);
}

private void OnButtonStraight(ClickEvent evt)
{
    Debug.Log("You Clicked the Straight Button!");
}

private void OnButtonCorner(ClickEvent evt)
{
    Debug.Log("You Clicked the Corner Button!");
}

private void OnButtonFloor(ClickEvent evt)
{
    Debug.Log("You Clicked the Floor Button!");
}

private void OnDisable()
{
    ButtonStraight.UnregisterCallback<ClickEvent>(OnButtonStraight);
    ButtonCorner.UnregisterCallback<ClickEvent>(OnButtonCorner);
    ButtonFloor.UnregisterCallback<ClickEvent>(OnButtonFloor);
}

And it works if the UI document is enabled or on at the start, but once I disable the UI document and re-enable it, the callbacks no longer work. I got around this by searching for the root visual element of the UI document from the first script and then turning its visibility on or off, you can see the edited script below:
public bool Locked;                     //the boolean value that controls if the spawnmenu is enabled
private GameObject Camera_Controller;   //the gameobject with the camera controller script on it
private VisualElement SpawnMenu;           //the UI document attached to this gameobject

// Start is called once before the first execution of Update after the MonoBehaviour is created
void Start()
{
    //set the gameobject to the LookTarget gameobject in the scene heirarchy 
    Camera_Controller = GameObject.Find("LookTarget");
    //set the locked variable equal to the RotationLock variable in the Camera_Controller script
    Locked = Camera_Controller.GetComponent<Camera_Controller>().RotationLock;

    //set the spawn menu equal to the UI document attached to this gameobject
    SpawnMenu = GetComponent<UIDocument>().rootVisualElement;
    //enable or disable the spawnmenu
    SpawnMenu.visible = Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    //determine the state of the locked variable and then enable or disable the spawn menu 
    Locked = Camera_Controller.GetComponent<Camera_Controller>().RotationLock;
    SpawnMenu.visible = Locked;
}

Why do the callbacks work while the document is enabled at the start, but then when the document is disabled and then enabled a second time do the callbacks no longer work? I found a fix by turning the visibility on and off but I would like to know why this is happening for future coding.

You are setting the callbacks in Awake instead of setting them in OnEnable.
As you can see in the lifecycle, Awake is not called again. It works once because Awake is called at the beginning.
You might as well change the Camera_Controller.GetComponent<Camera_Controller>() in Update and store it in a variable as reference to not every Update do the lookup.

+1. Yes, this is a common newbie mistake in UIToolkit. All the setup code for a UIDocument must happen in OnEnable, because the document root doesn't survive disabling and enabling. This is stated in the official documentation.

The script that i am making the callbacks in is a different script. So when i disable the UI document the callbacks are still "on". Changing the callbacks from the awake to OnEnable would not change anything. I have tested it though and it did not work.

A callback in your case is nothing more than the connection between button and called function. Usually you would have this script on the GO that has the buttons, you can still call the function from a different script/ GO. But if you never disable the script, it will not get reatteched to your buttons.

@user25832 As I said, you have to set up the event listeners each time the UIDocument gets enabled. If you prefer to have a different game object react to button clicks, then you are going to need a script on the document game object to maintain the event subscriptions on the document and makes them invoke events on itself which can then be subscribed to by other scripts.
